# How to make gulp write all files simultaneously?

Tags: gulp, pug-loader

I have a gulp task that bulids all my pug templates (with includes):

```
gulp.task('processMarkup', function(){
    return gulp.src('src/*.pug')
        .pipe(pug())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

I also have a watcher that runs this task:

```
gulp.task('watch-markup',function(){
    gulp.watch(['./src/**/*.pug'], gulp.series('processMarkup'));
});
```

Currently I have 5 pug templates inside my `src/` and each time when pug writes files to `dist/` (usually it takes 2-5s) my live-reload that observes `dist/` triggers browser reloading so i need to watch through 5 browser reloads.

I think this can be prevented if all files saved simultaneously. How it can be achieved? (or if you have better solutions suggest them).

P.S. Live Reload that i use https://github.com/tapio/live-server.

Comment: Have you tried using browserSync? It's reload can be triggered in series, so that it only reloads once after the `processMarkup` task completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the @Sean comment i made this config:

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let pug = require('gulp-pug');
let browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('reload', function(done) {
  browserSync.reload();
  done();
});

gulp.task('processMarkup', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/*.pug')
    .pipe(pug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});

gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: './dist/'
  });
  gulp.watch(['./src/**/*.pug'], gulp.series('processMarkup', 'reload'));
});
```

Now everything works properly.